# How do you find an old post?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago a Spanish gentlemen answered a post about installing a Wacom Intuos CTH-480 on an Ubuntu system and gave perfect easy to follow instructions that worked amazingly well. I can no longer find that post despite how I search for it. Does anyone remember this post? Or know the person I am describing?

I remembered most of the steps but when i go to copy kernel i.e. this one

cp 3.7/wacom.ko/lib/modules/3.11.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/input/tablet

I get no such file or directory in return despite I can see these files. Any ideas?

```
             Bruce
```

Comment: You are missing a space ` ` character between the `3.7/wacom.ko` and the path to copy it to (`/lib/modules/...`).

Comment: I am Italian :-)... the post is http://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395 (+1 for the gentlemen, hoping it was me).

Comment: That was it!! Sorry for calling you a Spaniard :-) earlier. Can not believe it was something so simple not spacing properly. Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 2):

I concur that the search engine of askubuntu is a bit strange (or I am not able to use it appropriately).

I normally use google directly: googling for

```
site:askubuntu.com CTH 480
```

will probably drop you to the correct answer.

Comment: Might I change this a bit? There is a nifty feature ;) `site:askubuntu.com` will limit the search to that domain